# get max value in java8 list using stream

Tags: list, java-8, java-stream

I want to find max value in java list using java8 lambda expression,
so, I have a Class called TicketMaster and item table is TicketMasterLog ,in TicketMasterLog class I have StatusMaster Class statusId reference column, so here i want to find max statusId in TicketMasterLog List, below i'll give my code please refer

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ticket_master")
@NamedQuery(name="TicketMaster.findAll", query="SELECT t FROM TicketMastert")
public class TicketMaster implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  @Id
  @Column(name="TICKET_ID", unique=true, nullable=false, length=10)
  private String ticketId;

  //bi-directional many-to-one association to TicketMasterLog
  @OneToMany(mappedBy="ticketMaster",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<TicketMasterLog> ticketMasterLogs;

 //getters and stters
}
```

and TicketMasterItem Table is

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ticket_master_log")
@NamedQuery(name="TicketMasterLog.findAll", query="SELECT t FROM   TicketMasterLog t")
public class TicketMasterLog implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@EmbeddedId
private TicketMasterLogPK id;
//bi-directional many-to-one association to StatusMaster
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="STATUS_ID")
private StatusMaster statusMaster;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to TicketMaster
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="TICKET_ID", nullable=false, insertable=false, updatable=false)
private TicketMaster ticketMaster;

//getters and setters

}
```

and StatusMaster Table is

```
@Entity
@Table(name="status_master")
@NamedQuery(name="StatusMaster.findAll", query="SELECT s FROM StatusMaster s")
public class StatusMaster implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name="STATUS_ID", unique=true, nullable=false, length=10)
private String statusId;

@Column(name="STATUS_NAME", length=45)
private String statusName;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to TicketMasterLog
@OneToMany(mappedBy="statusMaster")
private List<TicketMasterLog> ticketMasterLogs;

//getters and setters...
```

Now I have a TicketMasterlog List

```
List<TicketMasterLog> tl = //some objects;
```

so in that list I want find max status id value

thanking you.

Comment: Why not use order by and take first or max directly from DB?

Comment: hi Viktor, thanks for your reply.Its posible for getting max value from database but I'll get this max value in a loop , so in that loop may be more than 100 some times, so that,every time we need go for database query 100 times. so , avoid interaction to database every time , I'll try for lambda expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
Stream<TicketMasterLog> ticketMasterLogStream = tl.stream();
TicketMasterLog max = ticketMasterLogStream.reduce((a,b)-> 
    a.getStatusId.compareTo(b.getStatusId) > 0 ? a:b;
).get()
```

Comment: HI, its worikin fine thanks for your answer

Comment: Any reason not to use `Stream.max` for getting the maximum? `tl.stream().max(Comparator.comparing(TicketMasterLog::getStatusId)).get()`. Of course, you can do the same even without streams: `Collections.max(tl, Comparator.comparing(TicketMasterLog::getStatusId))`

Comment: No, but using reduce is a more general functional programming solution.
So if you learn how it works you can reuse more than "max".
Do more with less.
Reduce is very important in functional programming.

Comment: @Holger moreover the question ask to use a lambda expression.

Comment: Whether you write `TicketMasterLog::getStatusId` or `x -> x.getStatusId()`, is irrelevant. If you insist on using a lambda expression, use the latter. I still don’t see how you do “more with less”. You are *writing* more with `(a,b) -> a.getStatusId().compareTo(b.getStatusId()) > 0 ? a:b`, but achieving nothing more.

Comment: I mean that if you learn how to use "reduce" you'll be able to do more things than if you know  stream.max.

Comment: Sure. And if you know how to create a `Comparator` without verbosity nor code duplication, you can also do more things with it than querying the max value. And using a straight-forward solution designed for the actual task, is something worth learning too.